# How does PMX work?

Tags: music, musixtex, pmx

I need to implement music into a LaTeX document and MusiXTeX is difficult to understand. So I opted to use PMX. I've read the documentation for PMX and I think I've figured out how to write a `.pmx` file. However, what confuses me is how to actually turn the `.pmx` into something usable by LaTeX. It says to run `pmxab`, but it doesn't really provide step by step instructions on how to actually do so. Also, it says:

> The preamble ends with a line that contains the path name of the directory to which you
>   want the files (the .tex file, in particular) to be written when pmxab processes your source
>   text.

However, do I write the folder that the `.tex` file is in, or the name of the `.tex` file?

Edit:

Here is a sample `pmx` file that I wrote. I would like to know if it is written correctly.

```
1 1
3 4
3 4
0 1
0 4 16 0

./

e4d b8 e fs | g4 fs e | d4d e8 d4 | b2d //
```

Comment: Are you aware of [LilyPond](http://lilypond.org/)? It seems that this might be a preferable tool to use.  The issue with `.pmx` is that it produces a plain TeX file (not LaTeX) so integration into a LaTeX document is not straightforward.

Comment: @AlanMunn I know lilypond. However, I didn't know that you could implement lilypond into LaTeX. Is there a package or something?

Answer (score 2):

The following `.pmx` file produces proper output.  I don't know enough about PMX input to give you more pointers, however. I have added a clef, and changed the final `//` to `/`.  This was created with the command line command

```
 `musixtex <filename>.pmx`
```

where `<filename>` is your `.pmx` file name, e.g. if your file is `foo.pmx` then you use `musixtex foo.pmx`.

```
1 1
3 4
3 4
0 1
0 4 16 0

t % clef added here
./

e4d b8 e fs | g4 fs e | d4d e8 d4 | b2d /
```

The directory in which the `.tex` file will be written is notated by the `./` line at the end of the preamble. If you create a directory `mytex` inside the directory where the `.pmx` file is, then you could use `./mytex/` (final `/` is required), and the `.tex` file will be written to the `mytex` directory.  This directory must exist beforehand; it will not be created for you.

[image: ouptut of code]